# Magento database table is not displaying in custom module

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9, entity-attribute-value

I am working on a module for Magento 1.9.X. However, I am not able to create the database table `grided_products`. I have also checked `core_resource`, my module is updating the version also. Below are my codes

> config.xml

```
<modules>
    <Magento_Grided>
        <version>0.1.2</version>
    </Magento_Grided>
</modules>
        <models>
        <grided>
            <class>Magento_Grided_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>grided_resource</resourceModel>
        </grided>
        <grided_resource>
            <entities>
                <product>
                    <table>grided_products</table>
                </product>
            </entities>
        </grided_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <grided_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Grided</module>
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </grided_setup>
    </resources>
```

> upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.2.php

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();

$table = new Varien_Db_Ddl_Table();

$table->setName($this->getTable('grided/product'));

$table->addColumn(
'entity_id',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
10,
array(
    'auto_increment' => true,
    'unsigned' => true,
    'nullable'=> false,
    'primary' => true
)
);
$table->addColumn(
'created_at',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
null,
array(
    'nullable' => false,
)
);
$table->addColumn(
'updated_at',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
null,
array(
    'nullable' => false,
)
);
$table->addColumn(
'name',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
255,
array(
    'nullable' => false,
)
);

$table->setOption('type', 'InnoDB');
$table->setOption('charset', 'utf8');

$this->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$this->endSetup();
```

> Model/Product.php

```
<?php
class Magento_Grided_Model_Product extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('grided/product');
    }
}
```

> Model/Resource/Product.php

```
<?php
class Magento_Grided_Model_Resource_Product extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('grided/product', 'entity_id');
    }
}
```

> Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php

```
<?php
 class Magento_Grided_Model_Resource_Product_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract {
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('grided/product');
    }
}
```

Comment: in what folder is the `upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.2.php` file?

Comment: sql/grided_setup/upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.2.php